# Query to Select a "More Complete" Duplicate Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will select a "more complete" duplicate.  For example if our table contains the following 4 fields:  Name, Phone, Email, CompanyId, and both Name & CompanyId are equal for two records, but one of them contains a Phone and/or Email and the other record has these two fields blank, then only the completed record will be available in the recordset.

I thought I had the query down, but if a "more complete" record doesn't exist then that record is either left out completely or remained duplicated in the recordset (depending on how I modify the query).  I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing this that will not cause any data loss/duplication.  Right now all I can think of is to `UNION` a bunch more other queries, but I feel like there has to be a better way.  I'm using a CTE to get the raw data and then here's what I'm trying to do to manipulate it to remove duplicates:

```
;WITH Contacts AS ( 
     -- LONG QUERY HERE THAT UNIONS NECESSARY Tables & XML Columns AND returns a recordset with Name, Email, Phone, and ClientId
)
SELECT u.* FROM Contacts u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Name, ClientId, Count(*) AS ct FROM Contacts 
    GROUP BY Name, ClientId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS g
ON u.Name = g.Name AND u.ClientId = g.ClientId
WHERE Phone IS NOT NULL AND Email IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT u.* FROM Contacts u
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Name, ClientId, Count(*) AS ct FROM Contacts 
    GROUP BY Name, ClientId
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS h
ON u.Name = h.Name AND u.ClientId = h.ClientId
```

If unioning a few more queries is what is needed that's not a big deal, but it seems like there's probably a better way of handling this.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:  Sample Data

```
Name     |  Phone         |   Email       |  ClientId
------------------------------------------------------
Person1  |  NULL          |  NULL         | 42
Person1  |  555-555-5555  | test@blah.org | 42
Person2  | NULL           | NULL          | 21
Person2  | NULL           | NULL          | 21
Person3  | 555-555-5555   | NULL          | 79
Person3  | NULL           | NULL          | 79
Person4  | 555-555-5555   | NULL          | 49
Person4  | NULL           | test@blah.org | 49
Person5  | 555-555-5555   | NULL          | 91
Person5  | 555-555-5555   | test@blah.org | 91
Person6  | 555-555-5555   | NULL          | 91
```

Returned Dataset After Query --

```
Name     |  Phone         |   Email       |  ClientId
------------------------------------------------------
Person1  |  555-555-5555  | test@blah.org | 42
Person2  | NULL           | NULL          | 21
Person3  | 555-555-5555   | NULL          | 79
Person4  | 555-555-5555   | test@blah.org | 49
Person5  | 555-555-5555   | test@blah.org | 91
Person6  | 555-555-5555   | NULL          | 91
```

The merging of data for Person4 is the ideal situation, but not necessarily the answer I'm looking for in this SO question.  In that one situation where name OR email are populated I'd be OK with duplicates as long as there isn't any data loss.

Comment: Can you please show some actual data and expected data

Comment: @TheGameiswar I can't show actual data, but I'll mock some up give me a few minutes.

Comment: That would be helpfull,i meant sample data when i wrote actual data

Comment: Can you also paste some expected  output for one row say "Cheryl D\'Arrigo"

Comment: We need expected output for some sample rows,Can you plese update question with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for sure..

```
select 
name,max(phone),max(email),clientid
from
Table t
group by name,clientid
```

Comment: Simple and works for all of the scenarios that I've found so far!  I knew I was overthinking this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: :) But why `max()` ?

Comment: @Serg `MAX()` essentially does the null check and also will merge the fields together in the scenario in the sample data for Person4.

Comment: Min() does it too.

Comment: @Serg: max or min doesn't matter when you have nulls  in the case where one has data like the one op posted,i just posted using max

Answer (score 2):

This will return the "best" row for every `name`. Best means max number of extra columns (`Mail`, `Phone`) are not null.

```
select  top(1) with ties *
from Contact
order by row_number() over (partition by Name order by 
       case when Phone is null then 0 else 1 end + case when Email is null then 0 else 1 end desc)
```

Comment: 4th row needs to be merged ..Person4

Comment: Not sure about merging rules. Suppose we have one more nullable column `Skype` and both `Person4` rows have value, `abc`  and `xyz` for example. Which `Skype` should be in the merged row?

Comment: @Serg This is a good point, but in the data this never happens.  In the data there's never a scenario where there are duplicate records and both Email & Phone are populated (and not the same values).  It'll either be dupes with one having nothing, only email, only phone, or fully populated.  In the cases that it's only phone or only email they'll always have the same value in the duplicates if both dupes are populated.  I got lucky w/ the data being a mess, but still not so bad to manipulate.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 WITH CT AS(
           SELECT Name, Phone, Email, CompanyId,
    --This part determines duplicates by field 
               RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Name,CompanyId  ORDER BY Name)
           FROM Contacts
        )
        select FROM CT WHERE email <> '' and phone <> ''
```

To select duplicates based on specific columns do it here

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY {column1}, {column2}.....
```